# Running a python script from another script

Tags: python

I wish to a run a python script which takes options and arguments from another python script.

> ```
> For example run C:\\code\\old_start_training_generic_depth.py -i 10 -l 2 from 
> C:\\code\\start.py
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\code\start.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python", r"C:\code\old_start_training_generic_depth.py", "-i", "10", "-l", "2"])
```

Comment: Although it is often better to use `sys.executable` rather than hard coding `"python"` in order to cope with multiple versions of Python being installed on the system.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that using `subprocess.Popen`, which can be used to run any external process from your Python code (including other Python programs).

That said, I would do it otherwise. Since both programs are in Python, I would package the one you want to call as a module which can be invoked programmatically (i.e. imported and then called), instead of calling it as a subprocess. This may incur some small development cost but in the end I believe it will pay for itself, since this method has many advantages.

Comment: +1 for giving the answer that is needed, as well as the one that was asked for.

Answer (score 3):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\code\\old_start_training_generic_depth.py', '-i', '10', '-l', '2']).wait()
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just `communicate()` and throw away the results.

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

def runscript():
    '''
    Run a script
    '''

    cmd_list = ["python", r"C:\code\old_start_training_generic_depth.py", \
                "-i", "10", "-l", "2"]

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
    retcode = pipe.poll()

    return (retcode, stdout, stderr)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# once upon a time somewhere in the start.py
os.system("python C:\\code\\old_start_training_generic_depth.py -i 10 -l 2")
```

Comment: No! os.system is not the right way to do it.
[os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)

Comment: `os.system` would work perfectly fine. I guess what @Jakob means is that `subprocess.Popen` is a better alternative.

Comment: If you don't need to pass input/catch output I don't see what is wrong with the os.system.